# cannot add businessHours - weekends - fullcalendar v4

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Here is my fullcalendar config:

```
defaultView="resourceTimeGridDay"
```

and the resources

```
resources={[
                        {
                            id: 'a',
                            title: 'Resource A',
                            businessHours: {
                                startTime: '10:00',
                                endTime: '18:00'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'b',
                            title: 'Resource B',
                            businessHours: {
                                startTime: '11:00',
                                endTime: '17:00'

                            }
                        }
                    ]}
```

By default weekends are marked as non-business - grey background.

How can I add `businessHours` for Saturday and Sunday

Comment: Any error, or issue, please put your complete code then we will be able to reproduce your issue, it is fine if you create a demo

Answer (score 2):

```
daysOfWeek:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

in the business hours fix the issue.

```
businessHours: [ 
  {
    daysOfWeek: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], // enable all days
    startTime: '08:00',
    endTime: '18:00' 
  },
```